# how to make subclass :-TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sup(self):
         print(f'{self.name} {self.age} {self.language}')

class subclass(object):
    def __init__(self,language):
       Person.__init__(self,language)
       self.language

sm = subclass(input('input your name :') + input('input your age :') + input('input your language :'))
print(sm.sup())
```

Comment: expectation output is #satrio 20 blabla

Comment: `subclass` isn't actually a subclass of `Person`. And `Person.__init__(self,language)` is clearly wrong because what you're calling is defined with _three_ positional arguments `def __init__(self,name,age):`. How is `subclass` supposed to split up the three different things you've jammed together into one string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a working example for you. The code has many comments as explanation and for better understanding.

**Code:**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sup(self):
        # Change the "print" to "return" because the print is on caller side.
        return f"{self.name} {self.age} {self.language}"


# The "Subclass" is inherited from "Person"
class Subclass(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, language):
        # Call the __init__ method of parent class with the proper parameters
        super().__init__(name, age)
        # Set the "language" as instance variable.
        self.language = language


# The input parameters are separated so "," is needed instead of "+"
sm = Subclass(input("input your name: "), input("input your age: "), input("input your language: "))
print(sm.sup())
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
input your name: Bill
input your age: 53
input your language: English
Bill 53 English
```

**Notes:**

- I recommend to check the inheritation in Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp
- The `super()` is Python3 specific: https://realpython.com/python-super/